# How to log queries written in eclipse BIRT

Tags: sql, eclipse, logging, birt

I am currently using eclispe BIRT(Business Intelligence and Reporting Tool) 4.5.0 and have established jdbc connection. I want to know is there a way to log the queries written in query text window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it but it can help you : [See Jason answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/216762/)

> Entering script is pretty easy. Can you try clicking on your dataset
>   then hit the script tab on the report canvas and entering a beforeOpen
>   script,  something like:

```
       importPackage( Packages.java.io );
       out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "c:/temp/myquery.txt", true ) );
       out.println( "My Query: " + this.queryText);
       out.close();
```